# Send perl variables to a command and capture the output

Tags: perl, stdout

I'm attempting to pass perl variables into a system command and then capture the output for later usage, here's my current code:

```
my $updatedCmd = "|svn diff --summarize $svnOldFull $svnNewFull";
my $updatedUrls = '';
open UPDATES, $updatedCmd or die "Can't get updates";
while(<UPDATES>) {
  print $_;
}

print "THIS_SHOULD_OUTPUT_AT_THE_END\n";
```

The problem with this is that I get the output:

```
THIS_SHOULD_OUTPUT_AT_THE_END
A       /test
A       /test2
A       /deployment.txt
```

I would like to be able to capture all of the command output before allowing my perl script to go any further however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You placed the pipe on the wrong end of your command. Try this:

```
my $updatedCmd = "svn diff --summarize $svnOldFull $svnNewFull|";
```

Answer (score 5):

More modern way to do this is the following:

```
   my @cmd = qw(svn diff --summarize), $svnOldFull, $svnNewFull;
   open my $pipe, '-|', @cmd or die "oops: $!";
   while (<$pipe>) { ... }
```

Advantages

- no globals
- open mode separated from file/command
- command as array, so there is no need in shell quoting